# OpenID Connect relying party in .net

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

We have an OpenID Connect IdP already set up, but we now need a Relying Party based on .NET.  I've been looking at DotNetOpenAuth as a starting point.  Will that work?  What work would need to be done to communicate with an OpenID Connect IdP?

Answer (score 0):

No doubt you have done the google thing and found this already but just incase you haven't you may wish to have a look at this simple (really simple!) openid connect relying party in C#

[**Simple OpenID Connect Client in C#**](http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2012/07/how-simple-is-a-openid-connect-basic-client-c/)

which as my post states was a C# translation of a post by John Bradley